# Joining in PySpark gives unexpected results

Tags: python, join, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm using Spark version 2.0.0 with python version 3.5. I have a parent table with two columns: GroupID and ID. I need to break the data into 3 subsets so I am using stratified sampling.

Once I obtain my subset (sample A) I perform a left join and look for sample A IDs are null. The expected output is a subset of the parent table which does not contain any IDs from sample A.

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport().appName("myApp").getOrCreate()

data = [(0, 100), (0, 101), (0, 102), (0, 103), (0, 1000), (1, 104), (1,105), (1, 106), (1, 107), (1, 1007)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['group', 'id'])

## Stratified Sampling
fractions = dict((int(item), 0.45) for item in np.arange(0,(2)))
sampled_for_A = df.sampleBy("group", fractions, seed=7)
sampled_for_A.orderBy("id").show()

## Version 1

sampled_for_BC = df.join(sampled_for_A, df.id == sampled_for_A.id, "left_outer").select(df.group, df.id, sampled_for_A.group.alias("groupA"), sampled_for_A.id.alias("id_A"))
sampled_for_BC.where(sampled_for_BC.id_A.isNull()).show()
```

In version 1 the BC table is populated, but the values from the parent table are copied over.

```
Group A
+-----+----+
|group|  id|
+-----+----+
|    0| 101|
|    0| 102|
|    1| 104|
|    1| 105|
|    1| 107|
|    0|1000|
+-----+----+

BC
+-----+----+------+----+
|group|  id|groupA|id_A|
+-----+----+------+----+
|    1| 107|     1| 107|
|    0| 103|     0| 103|
|    1| 104|     1| 104|
|    0|1000|     0|1000|
|    1| 106|     1| 106|
|    0| 100|     0| 100|
|    1| 105|     1| 105|
|    1|1007|     1|1007|
|    0| 101|     0| 101|
|    0| 102|     0| 102|
+-----+----+------+----+
```

Version 2 createOrReplaceTempView and perform LEFT JOIN with sql query returns expected results

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("parentTable")
sampled_for_A.createOrReplaceTempView("groupA")

subset_BC = spark.sql(''' 
SELECT a.group,
   a.id,
   b.group AS group_A,
   b.id AS id_A
FROM parentTable a
LEFT JOIN groupA b
ON a.id = b.id
WHERE b.id IS NULL
''').show()
```

As expected:

```
BC
+-----+----+-------+----+
|group|  id|group_A|id_A|
+-----+----+-------+----+
|    0| 103|   null|null|
|    1| 106|   null|null|
|    0| 100|   null|null|
|    1|1007|   null|null|
+-----+----+-------+----+
```

What is it about the where clause in version 1 that I am missing? (Also my data has 100 million rows and even the sql left join performed in version 2 would behave strangely. I've also tried to repartition on group column.) Any insight is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `join` from version 1 is OK, but the next select overrides joined data. This is because `id` and `group` columns come from the same dataframe (`df`), so basically `df.group == sampled_for_A.group`.

To achieve wanted behaviour you must alias columns before joining, for example:

```
>>> sampled_for_A_aliased = sampled_for_A \
...     .select(sampled_for_A.id.alias('id_A'), sampled_for_A.group.alias('groupA'))
>>> df.join(sampled_for_A_aliased, df.id == sampled_for_A_aliased.id_A, "left_outer").show()
+-----+----+----+------+                                                        
|group|  id|id_A|groupA|
+-----+----+----+------+
|    1| 107|null|  null|
|    0| 103|null|  null|
|    1| 104| 104|     1|
|    0|1000|1000|     0|
|    1| 106| 106|     1|
|    0| 100|null|  null|
|    1| 105| 105|     1|
|    1|1007|null|  null|
|    0| 101| 101|     0|
|    0| 102| 102|     0|
+-----+----+----+------+
```